# Not able to query SharePoint from Nintex form custom JavaScript

Tags: sharepoint, nintex-workflow, sharepoint-jsom

I'm trying to query the SharePoint list using JSOM from Nintex custom javascript. My intention is to show the data in Nintex multiLine textbox. I can query data from SharePoint and display it in the Nintex edit form and not able to query from the Nintex view/display form.

Any thoughts? Thanks!.

Please refer the below code

```
 var clientContext;
    var oListItem;
    var workFlowListName = "sharepoint Tasks";
    var requestId = 1;
    var pollSP;

   function checkSPLoad() {
   if (clientContext) {
   window.clearInterval(pollSP);
   if (requestId)
   GetPFItems();
   }

  }

  function GetPFItems() {
   var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(workFlowListName);
   var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
   camlQuery.set_viewXml("<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ID' /><Value Type='Text'>" + requestId 
   + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>");
   this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
   clientContext.load(collListItem);
   clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.PFQuerySucceeded), 
   Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
   }

   function PFQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
   var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
   while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
   var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
   pfTaskName = oListItem.get_item('TaskName');

   NWF$('#'+'sampleTextBox').val(pfTaskName);
   }
   }

   function onQueryFailed(sender, args) { }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why your CAML Query has data type as `Text` for `ID` field? Also, You need to configure multiline textbox's setting and make `display mode` as `Edit`. This should start getting populated.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, After making the multiline textbox as editable it's working.